# Get Sum of weighted average over Interval

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

First of all, I'm using Microsoft Access 2002-2003 and using the query in VBA. Which means if possible I need a whole SQL string where I can insert the custom interval boundaries from VBA.

I have a table with this layout:

```
   Date   | Value  
1.1.2010      1  
1.1.2012      2  
1.1.2015      3
```

I need a SQL query that gets me the weighted average of the values in a variable Interval.

The idea is that the values apply from one date to the next, so the value 1 for example applies from 1.1.2010 to 31.12.2011 and so on.
The variable interval can (and will most of the time) cut into these, so if my interval is from 1.7.2010 to 1.7.2012 I need to consider 1.7.2010 - 31.12.2011 and 1.1.2012 - 1.7.2012
If the Interval starts before the first Date, the value of the first Date is used.

Two examples:
1.1.2010 - 31.12.2012 -> (2*1 + 2) / 3 = 1.33  (two years of 1 and one of 2)
1.1.2008 - 1.7.2012 -> (4*1 + 0.5 * 2) / 4.5 = 1.11 (four years of 1 and half of one of 2)

My biggest problems are getting these multiple intervals (especially with the custom interval) and getting the value to default to the first one if the interval starts before the first date.

My current query:

```
SELECT SUM(t2.Value * DateDiff("d",t2.date,t1.date)) AS s1, 
       SUM(DateDiff("d",t2.date,t1.date)) AS s2, s1 / s2 AS s3
FROM table AS t1,
     table AS t2
WHERE t2.date < t1.date
  AND NOT Exists (SELECT t3.date, t4.date
                  FROM table AS t3,
                       table AS t4
                  WHERE t1.date = t3.date AND t4.date <> t2.date
                    AND t4.date > t2.date AND t4.date < t1.date
                    AND t2.date < t1.date e);
```

This gives me something like this:

```
s1                  |      s2      |    s3
730 * 1  + 1096 * 2    730 + 1096      s1/s2
```

s1 is the weighted SUM of the intervals between the three dates (2010-2012, 2012-2015)
and s2 is the SUM of those two intervals (the 5 years)
and s3 is then the weighted average.

The query gets all intervals by just doubling the table, getting all dates that are smaller than another and then removing the ones that have a date in the interval with the `NOT EXISTS`

Now I just need to "add" the interval bounds into the equation...

The query that I have now only works with the table.
But I need it all with an Interval:
current output:

```
s1      |     s2    |   s3  
2922         1826       1.6
```

desired output with example interval of  1.1.2008 - 31.12.2016:

```
   s1        |    s2    |    s3  
   ~5841       3287      5841/3287`
```

so Intervals 1.1.2008 - 31.12.2011 with 1, 1.1.2012 - 31.12.2014 with 2 and 1.1.2015 - 31.12.2016

Comment: What do you mean with `Now I just need to "add" the interval bounds into the equation`? Do you mean that you want to include the highest date too, and weigh that for its date until today (or a certain other date)? Your approach seems valid (I could optimize it to run a lot faster, though). Please show the current output of the query (with your sample table), and the desired output of the query.

Comment: The query that I have now only works with the table.

Comment: But what do you want? We can't read your mind, if you want it to work with multiple tables, you have to tell us, provide the table structure, and be explicit about how you want those tables to work together

Comment: The query that I have now only works with the table.  
But I need it all with an Interval:
current output:
`    `s1      |     s2    |    s3 `     

    `2922      1826     1.6`

desired output with example interval of  1.1.2008 - 31.12.2016:  
`      `s1        |    s2    |    s3`  
    `~5841       3287      5841/3287`  

so Intervals 1.1.2008 - 31.12.2011 with 1, 1.1.2012 - 31.12.2014 with 2 and 1.1.2015 - 31.12.2016

Comment: Please edit your question to include that formatted.

Comment: ok, did that now. I'm new here, sorry

Comment: No problem, it's just hard for me to exactly understand what you want, and as you can see, that table is really hard to read in a comment. That's quite a complex thing you want, but I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a thorough rewrite of your query, added the parameters, and used the parameters instead of the lowest date for t2, and the highest date for t1.

Note that I've avoided the words `Date`, `Table` and `Value`, since these are SQL keywords, and not to be used for table or column names.

It's a bit much to go through at once, but if you have specific questions, I'll answer them.

Note that if you want to execute this query through VBA, you will have to set the parameters first.

```sql
PARAMETERS startInterval DateTime, endInterval DateTime;
SELECT SUM(t2.Weight *(IIF(t1.theDate IS NULL, endInterval, t1.theDate) - IIF(t2.theDate = (SELECT Min(theDate) FROM theTable), startInterval, t2.theDate))) AS s1, 
       SUM(IIF(t1.theDate IS NULL, endInterval, t1.theDate)  - IIF(t2.theDate = (SELECT Min(theDate) FROM theTable), startInterval, t2.theDate)) AS s2, s1 / s2 AS s3
FROM theTable AS t1 RIGHT JOIN 
     theTable AS t2 ON t2.theDate < t1.theDate
WHERE t1.theDate = (SELECT Min(t3.theDate) FROM theTable t3 WHERE t3.theDate > t2.theDate) OR t1.theDate IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
This isn't exactly what I needed, but thanks to your approach I found what I needed!